# Thread concurrency C program

Tags: c, concurrency

I wrote a C program with two threads. The first thread incrementing a counter as fast as it can, while the second thread occasionally read the counter value and print its value. Is posible to check if there is concurrency between threads ?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <cstdlib>


int counter = 0;
void* do_nothing(void *null) {
    while(true) {

        counter = counter % 10000000;
        counter++;
    }
} 

void* do_nothing1(void *null) {
    while(true) {
        if(rand()%10000000 == 5) printf("counter %d\n", counter);
    }
}       

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_t tid, tid1;
    pthread_attr_t attr; 
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);   
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    if (pthread_create(&tid, &attr, do_nothing, NULL)) {              
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create()");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (pthread_create(&tid, &attr, do_nothing1, NULL)) {              
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create()");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (pthread_join(tid, NULL)) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join()");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /*if (pthread_join(tid1, NULL)) {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join()1");
        exit(-1);
    }*/

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: If the printed value increases, then there is concurrency. Or maybe I don't understand what you're actually trying to check.

Comment: compiler optimizations in the first `do_nothing()` might make it a noop. I would declare variable as `int volatile count`

Comment: `do_nothing` seems to be an odd naming choice for functions that are actually doing something.

Comment: Does reeding counter can create concurrency ?

Comment: I don't think the word "concurrency" means what you think it means. Concurrency just means that two threads are running in parallel. Can you explain using other words?

Comment: I meen that two threads working on this same variable, this may cause some problems ?

Comment: yes it has concurrency problem due to counter increasing is not atomic operation.

Comment: I guess the term you are looking for is "race condition" then.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use printf() in do_nothing().
BTW, you have a few bugs in there but I can tell you are still learning.